# How to set a domain for a view [Odoo 15]

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

I want to have a view that only shows reservations with **state= 'paid_reserve'**. I have this code actually but it doesn't work.

```
 <record id="view_hotel_reservation_tree_paid" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">hotel.reservation.tree.paid</field>
        <field name="model">hotel.reservation</field>
        <field name="domain">[('state','=','paid_reserve')]</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml" >
            <tree>
                <field name="room_name" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="checkin" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="checkout" readonly="1"/>
                <field name="state" readonly="1"  />
            </tree>
        </field>
 </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain field is not available for views, you should see the following error in the log:

```
ValueError: Invalid field 'domain' on model 'ir.ui.view'
```

The domain can be used on the  [window action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window) to be implicitly added to all view search queries.

You can find the following example in the [account](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/views/account_move_views.xml#L1408-L1415) module:

```
<record id="action_account_moves_journal_sales" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="context">{'journal_type':'sales', 'search_default_group_by_move': 1, 'search_default_posted':1, 'search_default_sales':1, 'name_groupby':1, 'expand': 1}</field>
    <field name="name">Sales</field>
    <field name="res_model">account.move.line</field>
    <field name="domain">[('display_type', 'not in', ('line_section', 'line_note'))]</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_move_line_tree_grouped_sales_purchases"/>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,pivot,graph,kanban</field>
</record>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Kenly, it worked! I hope you can help me in my new question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74230496/how-to-add-a-new-measure-on-report-pos-order-odoo-15